# Exact ODE and the derivatives of the terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For an ODE of the following form:

$P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy=0$

why is it, that when we want to check whether the ODE is exact or not we derivate the first term w.r.t "y" and the 2nd term w.r.t "x" and not the reverse?

Answer (score 1):

We want to find a function F such that $$P(x,y)= \frac {\partial F}{\partial x}$$ and $$Q(x,y)= \frac {\partial F}{\partial y}$$
In order to  $$P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy=0 \iff \frac {\partial F}{\partial x}dx+ \frac {\partial F}{\partial y}dy=0$$
For such  a function $F$ to exist we need mixed partials to be commutative, thus $$\frac {\partial }{\partial y} P(x,y)=\frac {\partial }{\partial y} (\frac {\partial F}{\partial x})=
\frac {\partial }{\partial x} (\frac {\partial F}{\partial y})=\frac {\partial }{\partial x} Q(x,y) $$

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of the exact differential equation, if it's exact, then there exists a continuously differentiable function $U(x,y)$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial x} (x,y) = P(x,y), \;
\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial y} (x,y) = Q(x,y)
$$
However, [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Theorem_of_Schwarz) states that if some function has continuous second partial derivatives (or, equivalently, first partial derivatives are both continuously differentiable), then second partial derivatives commute. In case of mentioned $U(x,y)$, it means
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial y} (x,y)\right) =
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial x} (x,y)\right)
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial x} Q(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} P(x, y)
$$